# What is SMP and what role does it have while booting a computer?

Tags: linux, memory, cpu, smp

The boot process has an error at:

```
Freeing SMP alternative memory
```

and then hangs while boooting a notebook with Intel Celeron dual core and Linux.

What is SMP and what role does it have while booting a computer?

The problem is that the computer is unable to boot because of the above mentioned error in spite of a complete memtest done with no errors.

I was curious to know about this error and its significance at the boot process.

[image: snapshot]

Comment: "alternatives" is the Linux mechanism for switching between code optimized for UP (single-CPU) and SMP (multiple-CPU) without having to recompile the kernel.

Comment: I don't think that's the error point; I'd guess that it's probably the next step in the boot process that's causing problems, and crashes before it can print to console

Comment: @trapezoid ys, you are right, because on further reading, the problem points to bios settings for the sata hard drive. it should be changed to compatibility mode. Windows hangs on classpnp.sys while linux on SMP. Strangely, the installation process of both windows and linux has been a cake walk. The reboot poses an issue.

Comment: only unfortunately I cant test the bios yet, because of this problem - https://superuser.com/questions/1281797/how-to-update-compaq-cq61-presario-110es-bios-without-windows

Answer (score 0):

I'm running an IBM T500 laptop and it stopped during bootup init

Freeing SMP alternatives memory process:

I found that a BIOS change to the Intel Management Engine solved this issue.

1. boot to BIOS config, then CPU, then Intel AMD & toggle the
   enable/disable setting, save settings  reboot
2. When BIOS is doing its self check it will ask do you to unconfigure ME? Enter Y, BIOS will now update (insert magic here)

If there are any caveats to this process, reply

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).